# Title to be displayed below the headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I display Colors title below the headers in a table? Currently, I have Colors title on top of the headers but I need Colors title below the headers as a final output. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Well, you can directly update it in your csv or excel file?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the process. Client need it this way. Is this possible to get through the script? I have tried several ways without any success

Comment: There's a way to do so. `df.set_index('Column1')`, but I assume you need to change your column 1 name as `colors` first. If you don't mind changing the name of the columns, I can post an answer for it

Comment: Yeah, sure please share your idea. This is just an example that I have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas dataframe, if you want to show the name `Colors` below the header, you can rename your Column 1 as `Colors` and then set it as index.

```
data = {'Colors':['White','Black','Orange','Blue'],'Col2':[15,14,28,3],'Col3':[5,6,0,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

   Colors  Col2  Col3
0   White    15     5
1   Black    14     6
2  Orange    28     0
3    Blue     3     5

df.set_index('Colors', inplace=True)

        Col2  Col3
Colors            
White     15     5
Black     14     6
Orange    28     0
Blue       3     5
```

As you can see, the column `Colors` became index and your dataframe is left with two columns: `Col2` and `Col3`.